Which holomorphic maps $f:\mathbb{H}\to\mathbb{H}$ satisfy $f(z+1)=f(z)-1$?
Let $\mathbb{H}$ denote the upper half-plane. Which holomorphic maps $f:\mathbb{H}\to\mathbb{H}$ satisfy $f(z+1)=f(z)-1$ for all $z\in\mathbb{H}$?
My guess is that none exist. I think there might be orientation issues or something.
One observation that I made is that $e^{2\pi i f}$ is $1$-periodic. I was not able to get any use out of this though. I am quite stuck.
Do such maps exist? And if not, then why not?

$f(z)=-z$ is fine.

$-z$ does not send $\mathbb{H}$ to $\mathbb{H}$.

What is $\mathbb{H}$ ?

Upper half plane

The upper half plane, if OP's using the standard notation.

Yes, I mean the upper half-plane. I will add this in for clarity.

Also @RyszardSzwarc your example is essentially why I thought it might be an orientation issue. The only map that I could think of that satisfies this property and preserves $\mathbb{H}$ was $-\overline{z}$, but this is antiholomorphic rather than holomorphic.

There are no such holomorphic functions. The proof is largely topological. Consider the quotient map $z\mapsto \exp(2\pi i z), \mathbb H^2\to D^*=\{w: 0<|w|<1\}$, where $D^*$ is the quotient of $\mathbb H^2$ by the action of the group $\mathbb Z$ generated by the translation $g: z\mapsto z+1$. Since $f$ satisfies $f\circ g= g^{-1}\circ f$, the map $f$ descends to a holomorphic self-map
$$
h: D^*\to D^*. 
$$
The latter induces a homomorphism $\pi_1(D^*)\to \pi_1(D^*)$ sending the generator to its inverse. Hence, taking the counterclockwise oriented circle $C=\{w: |w|=1/2\}\subset D^*$, we see that the winding number $w(h(C))$ of $h(C)$ around $0$ equals $-1$. By the argument principle, since $w(h(C))=-1$, we get $Z(h) - P(h)=-1$, where $Z(h)$ is the number of zeroes of $h$ in the open unit disk $\Delta=\{w: |w|<1/2\}$ and $P(h)$ is the number of poles of $h$ in $\Delta$. However, since $h$ is bounded, it has no poles. This is a contradiction since $Z(h)\ge 0$.

Holomorphic functions mapping $H$ into itself are called Pick functions and have the following integral representation
$$f(z)=\alpha z+\beta +\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\gamma z+1}{\gamma -z}\mu(d\gamma)$$ where $\mu$ is a bounded positive measure, $\alpha\geq 0$ and $\beta$ is a real number. The theorem is due to Nevanlinna. For your $f$ we have $f(z) +z=g(z)$ where $g$ as period one and is also a Pick function with the same $\mu$ and $\beta$ but where the $\alpha$ component is replaced by $\alpha+1>0.$ If we watch $t\mapsto h(t)=g(i\epsilon +t)$ clearly $h$ is the sum of non zero affine function and of a bounded continuous function and cannot be periodic since it is not bounded.

Perhaps $h(t)$ should be $g(t+i\varepsilon).$

Oh thanks. I am making the correction.

For reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nevanlinna_function

I also like this answer, and I have upvoted it. If I could accept multiple answers I would. Thank you for posting it!

Suppose such a function $f(z)$ exists; we will arrive at a contradiction. First note that $g(z) = f(z) + z$ has period $1$ and thus can be expanded in the form
$$g(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_n e^{2\pi i n z}$$
You can see this by looking at ${\displaystyle h(z) = g\bigg({\log z \over 2\pi i}\bigg)}$, an analytic function on $\{z: 0 < |z| < 1\}$ and using the Laurent series expansion of $h(z)$. Note that $g(z)$ also maps $\mathbb{H}$ to itself. This precludes $h(z)$ from having either a pole or an essential singularity at $z = 0$ because in either case the range of $g(z) $ will then not be contained in $\mathbb{H}$ due to the behavior of $h(z)$ near $0$, which translates into corresponding behavior for $g(z)$ for large Im $z$.
Thus the only remaining possibility is that $h(z)$ has a removable singularity at $z = 0$. This means that $a_n = 0$ for all $n < 0$ and we may write
$$f(z) = -z + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n e^{2\pi i n z}$$
If we move upwards along the imaginary axis $f(z)$ will eventually lie outside of $\mathbb{H}$ since the series tends to $a_0$. Thus we have a contradiction and no such $f(z)$ exists.

I thought there should be a rather elementary proof along these lines, but failed to see the idea of excluding a singularity at $0$. Well done.

I have a question about this answer. I agree that $h$ cannot have an essential singularity at the origin. I don't immediately see why $h$ cannot have a pole at the origin though. You say this is "because $g$ maps $\mathbb{H}$ to itself," but there are plenty of self-maps of $\mathbb{H}$ that exhibit this behavior (e.g., $z\mapsto -1/z$). I guess I can see it if you quotient the target space by $z\mapsto z+1$ and descend to the punctured disk like in Moishe's answer. Is that would you had in mind?

@4plus4man Suppose $h(z)$ had a pole of order $k$ at the origin. On a small circle centered at the origin, $h(z)$ wraps around the origin clockwise $k$ times. In particular the range of $h(z)$ will leave ${\mathbb H}$. Translated in terms of $g(z)$, on a horizontal line Im$(z)= N$ for large enough $N$, $g(z)$ will leave ${\mathbb H}$.
